# jQuery datepicker confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this weird requirement with jQuery `datepicker`. I have a `datepicker` attached to an input, which already has dates fetched in from database. Now what I am looking to achieve is once I click on the input box the datepicker appears (default functionality of datepicker) and when I click on any other dates, it want a simple JavaScript confirm box with *OK* and *Cancel*, so clicking *OK* will change the dates and clicking *Cancel* will not.

Any idea how to do that?. I was able to create the confirm box and attach it to `onSelect` event from the `datepicker`. But the `datepicker` still changed dates even after clicking *Cancel*.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (e) {
               var popup = confirm("Do you want to change dates?");
               if (popup == true) {

               } else {
                  return false
               }
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi there, can you show the code that creates the confirm box and how you attach it to the `onSelect` event? A JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570375/jquery-ui-datepicker-within-jquery-confirm-dialog

Comment: I think on Cancel you just neet to re-assign the default/ previously updated date

Comment: @ShaileshRathod , I am trying not to re-assign the older value. There are some other operations that depends on the changed value, so I would like to prevent the value from updating in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous value in data attribute and when canceled set the previous value. Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.date').data("prev", $(this).val());
    $('.date').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (e) {
           var prevDate = $(this).data("prev");
           var popup = confirm("Do you want to change dates?");
           if (popup == true) {
                $('.date').data("prev", $(this).val());
           } else {
              $( ".date" ).datepicker('setDate',prevDate);
           }
       }
    });
});
```